# PHPStorm : How do I set "Do not auto open Tools Window"

Tags: ide, settings, phpstorm

Every time I get latest code from SVN or upload my project, the tools window auto open at bottom. I would like it to open only when I click on "Changes" or "File transfer" tab at the bottom. Any help please?

Comment: What version of phpstorm are you using and what OS? I have pinned and docked options checked and the windows only open after I click on them.

Comment: Thank you dmullings.
Mac Mavericks ver 10.9.4    PHPStorm 7.1
I made below changes to resolve the issue.
1. Uncheck pinned and docked options for these windows
2. Uncheck "Auto Show" from Windows->Background Tasks->Auto Show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When File Transfer window tool is opened You have to disable Docked Mode and Floating Mode. These options are on the right side of the window (cog icon).